# Can you use parameters from the DIC in routes? (method parameter injection)

Tags: dependency-injection, routes, symfony

I've got some services that are being hit with a certain tag in my Symfony2 project that I'd like to use inside of a controller.

As a result, I'm trying to figure out the best way to get them passed to the controller, and thought that perhaps there's a way to do it with Symfony2's overall configuration system.

```
#  Inside routing.yml:
my_controller:
  pattern: "/path"
  defaults {
      _controller: Bundle:Controller:action
      # The following line is kind of what I'm looking for.
      myParam: @my.tag
  }

# Inside a services.yml file:
my.service:
  class: Bundle\MyService
  tags:
      - { name: my.tag }
my.otherService:
  class: Bundle\MyOtherService
  tags:
      - { name: my.tag }
```

Given the two config file examples above, I'd like it so that my instance of "Bundle:Controller:action" receives an array containing instances of "Bundle\MyService" and "Bundle\MyOtherService".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This discussion on google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/ca088434adde3f68) has resulted in a solution.  Some of the API however has changed.  Namely:

- The bundle method you override is build(), not registerExtensions().
- The extension method you overload is load() not configLoad().

So long as you move the two blocks of code accordingly and implement it correctly, you should be able to get something along the lines of the functionality I want.

Sadly, this isn't in any way automated by the DIC, but it's important to note that I do have the requirement of getting everything of a specific tag.  Not just from my bundle, but from every bundle ultimately becoming part of the app.